# pandas: groupby multiple columns, concatenating one column while adding another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

If I had the following df:

```
      amount   name   role    desc
0        1.0    a      x       f
1        2.0    a      y       g
2        3.0    b      y       h
3        4.0    b      y       j
4        5.0    c      x       k
5        6.0    c      x       l
6        6.0    c      y       p
```

I want to group by the `name` and `role` columns, add up the `amount`, and also do a concatenation of the `desc` with a `,` :

```
      amount   name   role    desc
0        1.0    a      x       f
1        2.0    a      y       g
2        7.0    b      y       h,j
4        11.0   c      x       k,l
6        6.0    c      y       p
```

What would be the correct way of approaching this?

Side question: say if the `df` was being read from a .csv and it had other unrelated columns, how do I do this calculation and then write to a new .csv along with the other columns (same schema as the one read)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

May be not exact dupe but there are a lot of questions related to groupby agg

```
df.groupby(['name', 'role'], as_index=False)\
.agg({'amount':'sum', 'desc':lambda x: ','.join(x)})


    name    role    amount  desc
0   a       x       1.0     f
1   a       y       2.0     g
2   b       y       7.0     h,j
3   c       x       11.0    k,l
4   c       y       6.0     p
```

Edit: If there are other columns in the dataframe, you can aggregate them using 'first' or 'last' or if their values are identical, include them in grouping.

Option1:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'role'], as_index=False).agg({'amount':'sum', 'desc':lambda x: ','.join(x), 'other1':'first', 'other2':'first'})
```

Option 2:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'role', 'other1', 'other2'], as_index=False).agg({'amount':'sum', 'desc':lambda x: ','.join(x)})
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Vaishali. Do you know how to include the rest of the columns that are in the `df` ? They haven't been modified nor are they to be used in groupby, but I need them when I want to write to .csv.

Comment: When you group the data, you need to aggregate every column using some method. Eg- you have two rows corresponding to name b and role y at index 2 and  3 respectively, so after aggregation what values of those rest of the columns would you like to keep in your resulting data frame?

Comment: is it possible to just take the value from one of the rows? No sort of aggregation/sum/concatenation needed, there won't be much or any difference between the rows other than the `amount` and `desc` columns.

Comment: In that case, you can aggregate using 'first' or 'last', they return the first or the last row for each group

Comment: I had the same question as @averageUsername123 and ended up using a dict to handle the remaining columns. Code in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Vaishali's answer. To handle the remaining columns without having to specify each one you could create a dictionary and have that as the argument for the agg(regate) function.

```
dict = {}
for col in df:
    if (col == 'column_you_wish_to_merge'):
        dict[col] = ' '.join
    else:
        dict[col] = 'first' # or any other group aggregation operation

df.groupby(['key1', 'key2'], as_index=False).agg(dict)
```